# Laravel elixir installation error

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to install laravel elixir but I'm getting this error:

[image]

Anyone knows where can be a problem?

Comment: Move it away and try again.

Comment: yup I did that command twice and it works now

Answer (score 0):

please check your package.json file, it should be like

```
{
"private": true,
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-notify": "^2.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
"laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
"socket.io": "^1.4.5"
 }
}
```

then check gulpfile.js, it should be like, i added only css file.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.styles([
    "common.css",
    "bootstrap.min.css"
 ], 'public/css/all.css').version('public/css/all.css');
});
```

then run "npm install"
it will load all dependencies

then run "gulp"
it will compile your elixir files